# Printing XML encoded Text.XML.HaXml.SAX.SaxElement elements

Tags: xml, haskell, haxml

I have SaxElement from Sax parser in HaXml. What is the best way to print valid XML encoded text back from SaxElement elements? Especially I am interesting in printing XML-encoded text from SaxReference. Unfortunately SaxElement is not a member of Show type class and show of internal types like Reference does not return XML-encoded text. For example "&" is printed back by show as RefEntity "amp".

I tried to make SaxElement member of Show. But it is not complete and looks ugly. Is there a better way?

```
instance Show(SaxElement) where
    show (SaxDocTypeDecl decl) = "<!-- TODO: doctype -->"
    show (SaxProcessingInstruction pi) = "<!-- TODO: processing instruction -->"
    show (SaxComment s) = "<!--" ++ s ++ "-->"
    show (SaxElementOpen n attrs) = "<" ++ n ++ ">" -- TODO: attributes 
    show (SaxElementClose n) = "</" ++ n ++ ">" 
    show (SaxElementTag n attrs) = "<" ++ n ++ "/>" -- TODO: attributes
    show (SaxCharData cd) = cd -- TODO: encode? 
    show (SaxReference r) = show(r) -- TODO: not encoded!
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a Show instance for SaxElement you can use the `StandaloneDeriving` pragma like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

import Text.XML.HaXml.SAX

deriving instance Show SaxElement
```

You will get a warning about creating an "orphan" instance, but this is not a problem for debugging or testing.

Comment: Won't that just output the xml as a haskell type?  I think @Vladimir wants well formulated xml.